# Elsevier's confusing guide for authors

Tags: publications, paper-submission, elsevier

I am trying to submit a manuscript to an Elsevier journal [Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews (RSER)](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/renewable-and-sustainable-energy-reviews/1364-0321/guide-for-authors) and found the author guidelines most confusing. For example, under author guidelines, it is said that

> **Use of word processing software**

> It is important that the file be saved in the native format of the
> word processor used. The text should be in single-column format. Keep
> the layout of the text as simple as possible. Most formatting codes
> will be removed and replaced on processing the article. In particular,
> do not use the word processor's options to justify text or to
> hyphenate words.

Then it recommends

> to use the latest Elsevier article class to prepare your manuscript
> and BibTeX to generate your bibliography.

Now, there are two classes and templates available for Latex: `cas-dc` and `cas-sc`, one for the double column and one for the single column. Now I am confused,

(a) Which template to use for the submission? Single column `cas-sc` or double column `cas-dc`? The author instructions or the user guide for the templates does not guide when to use which template.

(b) The aforementioned instructions are for the source file? Latex source file is already in the single column format.

(c) What should be the layout of the output PDF? Single column or double column? The journal publishes article in the double column format!

(d) Should the PDF files have justified text or ragged right? Latex templates provided by Elsevier produce PDF files with justified text.

I will be thankful if someone can help me out with this. The confusing author guidelines can be found [here](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/renewable-and-sustainable-energy-reviews/1364-0321/guide-for-authors).

Comment: 1. Some journals do review process on the single column, and after acceptance they transform it to double column. 
2. Templates are not designed only for one journal. So, sometimes you can see different templates while downloading their zip file. (for example 3 or more of the Elsevier journals refer to one file, and the others refer to the second one.)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Elsevier guide for authors is almost the same for all its journals. However, it is the most confusing. What I am interested in is answers to my queries (a) to (d) in my post.

Comment: I think its better to be written in single col format. But it is not that important, don't worry, If you select the wrong template, they tell you after submission. Usually it doesn't endanger the review process. You can even send email and ask them beforehand.

Comment: @m123 I think that would be a fine answer.

Comment: I think the two sections are best understood if you consider the first as instructions for authors not using LaTeX and the second for LaTeX users.

Comment: At the stage of submission it usually doesn't matter. If your paper is accepted, they might ask you to reformat it (or do it themselves).

Comment: If a specific publishing company's instructions are unclear I'd recommend contacting the company. Let them clear up their mess!

Comment: As a LaTeX user, I'd use the cas-sc class, because the paragraph about "word processing  software" (which is mostly irrelevant to me) requests single-column format. But I don't think they'd object if you used cas-dc, since it's included in their recommendation for LaTeX. I personally would not use BibTeX, because of bad experiences with it, but if you haven't had such experiences, go ahead and use it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I'm curious, what do you use instead of BibTeX?

Comment: I back up the answer of @sleepy. In my experience as editor, 60% of people who submit ignore the author guidelines anyway, and upon acceptance they are then more clearly asked what they need to do.

Comment: There are a number of valuable comments with very good advice. Yet there is no answer to the question I posted. I am happy to have some sound advice. I am also a bit relieved to know that I am probably not the only one who is confused and could not make sense of Elsevier's guide. Otherwise, there would have been an answer by now.

Comment: @astronat I just write out the references myself, in the main LaTeX file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different fields have different conventions. I am a mathematician, and my advice reflects what I know about publishing conventions in that field. So please take this advice with a grain of salt.

This said: Echoing the comments of m123, sleepy, and Lewian, I would advise you to **ignore Elsevier's guidelines entirely.** Submit your document in any format which looks attractive, is normal for your field, and is convenient for you to prepare.

You can worry about their guidelines once your paper is accepted, and maybe not even then. My own opinion is that if Elsevier [charges $4,034.00](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/institutional/renewable-and-sustainable-energy-reviews/1364-0321) for an annual subscription to this journal, then perhaps they can afford to employ staff to do their own formatting work.